# Promise prints out response but doesn't return anything on Facebook API graph call

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, promise

This code will print out all the console.logs inside the promise, but when the last lines of code (res, and item) will print out empty. Additionally, nothing gets concatenated to 'friends'.

The last lines of output look like this

`friends []
    res.data.paging.next     https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/101549438291/taggable_friends?    access_token=12345
    friends []
    res.data.paging.next undefined
    res []
    items []`

```js
// Get friends
            var items = [];

            async function getFriends() {
              let friends = [], hasNext = true;
              var friendsUrl = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/me/taggable_friends?access_token=' + accessToken;

              while (hasNext) {
                await new Promise(resolve => {
                  axios.get(friendsUrl)
                    .then(function(res) {
                      friends.concat(res.data.data);
                      items.concat(res.data.data);
                      console.log('friends', friends);
                      // console.log('res.data.data', res.data.data)
                      console.log('res.data.paging.next', res.data.paging.next);

                      if (!res.data.paging.next) {
                        hasNext = false;
                      } else {
                        friendsUrl = res.data.paging.next;
                      }
                    })
                    .then(function() {
                      resolve();
                    })
                    .catch(function(err) {
                      console.log('err', err);
                    });
                });
              }
              return friends;
            }

            getFriends().then((res) => {
              console.log('res', res);
              console.log('items', items);
            });
```

Why is this and how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

The function concat does not mutate the array:

```js
const friends = [];
friends.concat("new item");
console.log(friends);//is still []
```

I have cleaned up your code a little and use recursion instead of while loop.

```
const Fail = function(reason){this.reason=reason;};
const isFail = x=>(x&&x.constructor)===Fail;
function getFriends(friendsUrl,friends=[]) {
  console.log('friends', friends);
  axios.get(friendsUrl)
  .then(function (res) {
    // console.log('res.data.data', res.data.data)
    console.log('res.data.paging.next', res.data.paging.next);
    if (!res.data.paging.next) {
      return friends.concat(res.data.data);
    }
    return getFriends(
      res.data.paging.next,
      friends.concat(res.data.data)
    );
  })
  //when there is an error return error type with the friends you got so far
  .catch(
    e=>new Fail([e,friends])
  );
}

getFriends('https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/me/taggable_friends?access_token=' + accessToken)
.then((res) => {
  if(isFail(res)){
    console.error(
      "There was an error:",
      res.reason[0],
      "friends so far:",
      res.reason[1]
    );
  }else{
    console.log(
      "all is fine, complete friends list:",
      res
    );
  }
});
```